# Websites hosted on different servers being hacked 'again and again' with same base64 malware codes

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp, malware

My Websites hosted on different servers being hacked again and again with same base64 malware codes. When I decoded the base64 code I got the link to mbrowserstats.com/statH/stat.php.

Please note: My websites with core php and also wordpress are being hacked. They are placing base64 malware codes in following files - index.php, main.php, footer.php, template files of wordpress (index.php, main.php, footer.php), index.php files in wp-admin, plugins, themes folders etc.

I have already tried below things but all websites are being hacked again and again.

- Changed all ftp passwords
- Changed ftp client fileZilla to winSCP
- Removed all malware codes and re-upload all files to server
- Uploaded old backup files without malware codes
- Disabled magic_quotes_gpc, register_globals, also exec & shell_exec functions
- Used index files to prevent direct folder access
- Used mysql_real_escape_string function to sanitize data for insert queries in php websites
- Updated WordPress and also all Plugins to latest version
- Installed malwarebytes anti-malware and scanned my computer for malwares (Full Scan)
- Confirmed that my websites are not using timthumb.php file
- Changed file permissions (755 for folders & 644 for files). Now only image upload folders have 777 permission.

When I checked the websites' visitor details I found some IPs like 150.70.172.111 / 150.70.172.202, Hostname:150-70-172-111.trendmicro.com, Country - Japan. They accessed websites in close times to the time that of modified files (malware injected files).

Additional Information: I'm using Trend Micro antivirus from last 1 year. I'm wondering that the IPs with hostname 'trendmicro.com' have any relation with hacking or in stealing my ftp passwords.

I suspect that they are using ftp access to insert malware codes. Also the time between file modifications is very low. They have updated all files within seconds. So I think they are using a program for that. Manually they cannot edit all files within seconds as I have so many files in different folders of same website.

Please help me to resolve this issue. I have tried many things but it happens again. Thanks

Comment: Since we (and probably you) don't know very much information, it is hard to determine what is happening. Is it shared hosting or dedicated? Are the two servers from the same provider or different? What OS is on the servers?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. Those websites are on different servers. And yes it's using shared hosting. I'm not sure about their Os but I think it will be linux based. But I have noted that another wordpress website in the same server of my wordpress website is still not affected with malwares.

Comment: I would start by contacting the server admin and requesting a list of all FTP and SSH logins for your account. If SSH is enabled on the server, is it only password authentication or also public key authentication? If pubkey is enabled, you need to check the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file and remove any unknown entries. Also, make sure to change your SSH password if that is different from FTP.

Comment: Also, have you connected to FTP on a wireless connection? If so, that's a bad idea. FTP is unencrypted and anyone who can sniff your connection can easily steal your login credentials. Contact your server about how to securely transfer files (sftp, ftps, scp, etc).

Comment: Hi, "FTP on a wireless connection" - Are you asking about my internet connection? If so, Yes I'm using wireless 3G connection and sometimes wireless EVDO connection.  I'm using normal FTP access as I'm not able to connect to server in 'SFTP' mode. Is it depends on server? I have contacted the server admin and he told I can change php settings in my website itself and i have disabled magic_quotes_gpc, register_globals, exec & shell_exec. Kindly suggest me what should I ask the admin for the reason or prevention for hacking... Thanks

Comment: If you have any folders that are permission 777, anyone else on the server can modify your files. This is a very bad idea for shared hosting. "Other" should never have write access to any of your files or folders.

Comment: But without 777 permissions image uploads won't work in worpress/php right? I have uploads folder with 777 permission in wordpress website. Also image upload folder in a php website. Is it possible to edit my files in other folders if I use 777 for upload folder? They are editing many files in almost all folders for putting malware codes

Comment: If php is executed as the website owner's user, 777 is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tricky to handle this. One of the common ways this happens is that on a shared server a malicious user can use another account and insert a file in your upload directory (which is often world writeable on shared servers) by going down and back up the filesystem. It's not really an issue of passwords being cracked. Things you can do:

1. Use a private/virtual server- just not the standard shared type with more than one user in the same filesytem
2. Keep WordPress updated
3. Check all your theme and plugins for online notices of vulnerabilities. A big one is that many themes use timthumb.php for image resize which had a big security hole last year. You can continue using it but make sure to replace it with the current version.

For hosting I highly recommend using something such as http://WPEngine.com as you will not only get a private experience but they will also be more top of security scans than standard hosting companies.

Also if your site has been hacked you must be very very careful to remove all backdoors - I recommend doing a clean install which is obviously tough since you have to put your theme back and that can contain backdoors as well. Malicious users will create multiple backdoors in case one gets taken down. There are a few scripts online that will scan for these but none that is perfect.  Making a cleab install, then backing it up offline in case of a hack is a good option.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I'm using latest version of wordpress and my files doesn't contain timthumb.php. Also uploaded all old backup files before hacking. But they hacked my website again.. Please give any suggestion - How can I prevent this hacking or find out how it happens? Thanks

Comment: Are you on a shared server? I would change hosting.  A common way for an attack to occur is through directories/files that have too open of permissions. The issues with shared servers is that sometimes you need those to be open though more hosting companies are changing this. You'd want to make sure that no directories or files are writeable except by your user (755 for directories and 644 for files). But I recommend going with a private/virtual private server like wpengine.